# How to access Chrome developer tools for automation?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, google-chrome-devtools, exe

Is it possible to write a script which would let me access the Chrome developer tools. To be more specific, I would like to create an exe or batch file which would open Chrome and then automatically load it to 
a particular device mode or access the other tabs, available in Chrome developer tools(Ctrl+shift+I). I'm not sure about my approach.

What language should I write this script in? Will a batch file do the trick? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about a batch file, since you'd be limited to whatever command line arguments the exe could take.  You could use something like selenium to try to rig something up, but UI automation like that is usually a little picky from time to time.

Comment: Selenium is not exactly what I was looking for, would like to know if there is any other method that I can approach. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to simulate key presses, you might have some luck with the `SendKeys` function of vbscript.